# Regular Expression in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

How do you trim all of the text after a comma using JS?

I have: `string = Doyletown, PA`

I want: s`tring = Doyletown`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a split:

```
var string = 'Doyletown, PA';
var parts = string.split(',');
if (parts.length > 0) {
    var result = parts[0];
    alert(result); // alerts Doyletown
}
```

Comment: What? the length will always be greater then or equal to 1! This is not a very well done example nor would I suggest using a method that makes an entire array and will internally have to iterate through the entire string even if it finds a "," right away.

Answer (score 6):

```
var str = 'Doyletown, PA';
var newstr=str.substring(0,str.indexOf(',')) || str;
```

I added the `|| str` to handle a scenario where the string has no comma

Comment: @teneff +1, removed my version.

Answer (score 1):

using regular expression it will be like:

```
var str = "Doyletown, PA"
var matches = str.match(/^([^,]+)/);
alert(matches[1]);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAkGw/)

btw: I would also prefer `.split()` method

Comment: That should be `matches[0]`. `[1]` does not even exist because you did not use a `g` match.

Answer (score 0):

Or more generally (getting all the words in a comma separated list):

```
//Gets all the words/sentences in a comma separated list and trims these words/sentences to get rid of outer spaces and other whitespace.
var matches = str.match(/[^,\s]+[^,]*[^,\s]+/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = str.replace(/,.*/, '');
```

Or play with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPfvQ/2/)